# Disable popup in select box in android device

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to show select dropdown box without showing popup style in Android device? I want the select dropdown box will act normal like normal dropdown style desktop view. But in Android devices, the select box is always showing like a popup which I don't want. So can it be possible?

Comment: Remove `data-native-menu="false"`.

Comment: @Omar thanks for your reply..but there is nothing like the code "data-native-menu" on the page which i can remove..

Comment: can you show your code?